# Flutter - how do I create a modified version of basic material widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm looking to modify the `Stepper` widget from flutters material widgets.
In particular I'd like to have a version that does not include the `Continue` and `Cancel` buttons but only uses the `onStepTapped` callback for navigation.

My initial thought was just to `extend` the Stepper class, but since it's a stateful widget the building happens in the `_StepperState` class. I guess I'd have to extend that as well and create a new stateful widget extending Stepper and it's state extending StepperState. The latter is not exposed through the `flutter/material.dart` though and I can't seem to extend it easily to override the `_buildVerticalControls` method.

Being new to flutter and dart I'm now wondering what the correct way would be to extend / modify existing (stateful) widgets without `c&p`-ing the entire class?

Comment: There's no easy solution here. Either edit flutter sources (and make a potential PR) or fork that code to make it your own.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think i may know how to do it, just go to your flutter sdk, wherever you have installed it, and finid stepper.dart file inside something like packages//src/material/ or something and in that file find a function named

```
Widget _buildVerticalBody(int index)
```

and from the body of this function find the statement

```
_buildVerticalControls()
```

and comment out the call of that function like this

```
//_buildVerticalControls()
```

voila the buttons are gone ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's already answered but I think you could use the [controlsBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Stepper/controlsBuilder.html) property, then you could just add an empty container to avoid showing the buttons (didn't test myself but I think this could just work).